# Symfony2 OneToMany does not use custom repository class

Tags: symfony, doctrine, repository

I have to tables

preset_item
id

and

preset_item_element
preset_item_id -> reference to prese_item
element_type
element_id

in PresetItemElement entity there is:

```
/**
 * @var \GGG\ManagerBundle\Entity\PresetItem
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GGG\ManagerBundle\Entity\PresetItem", inversedBy="elements")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="preset_item_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $presetItem;
```

and in PresetItem

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PresetItemElement", mappedBy="presetItem")
 */

private $elements;

public function getElements()
{
    return $this->elements;
}
```

And preset Item have custom Repository class:

```
/**
 * PresetItem
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="preset_item")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="GGG\ManagerBundle\Entity\PresetItemRepository")
 */
class PresetItem
```

it's looks like that:

```
<?php
namespace GGG\ManagerBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\LockMode;
class PresetItemElementRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null) {
        return $this->decorate(parent::findBy($criteria, $orderBy, $limit, $offset));
    }

    public function find($id, $lockMode = LockMode::NONE, $lockVersion = null) {
        return $this->decorateElement(parent::find($id, $lockMode, $lockVersion));
    }

    public function findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null) {
        return $this->decorateElement(parent::findOneBy($criteria, $orderBy));
    }



    private function decorateElement($element) {
        $object = $this->getEntityManager()
                    ->getRepository(
                            'GGGManagerBundle:'.$element
                            ->getPresetItemElementType()
                            ->getRepresentationObject()
                    )->findOneBy(array('id' => $element->getElementId()));
        $element->setObject($object);
    }


    private function decorate($elements) {

        foreach($elements as $element) {
            $this->decorateElement($element);
        }
        return $elements;
    }   
}
```

So i'm decorating each PresetItemElement with some additional data

and it's work when i;m getting single PresetItemElement object but when i'm getting PresetItem and try iterate getElements()

```
    $entity = $em->getRepository('GGGManagerBundle:PresetItem')->find($id);

    foreach($entity->getElements()  as $a) {
        var_dump($a->getObject());
    }
```

i have null here, it looks like custom PresetItemElementRepository was not executed

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine doesn't use repositories internally when loading related entities. Also, when using for example a query or the query builder to retrieve entities, the repository wouldn't be used either.

To do something every time an entity is loaded from the database, you should register an event handler for the postLoad event. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html for how to write and register event listeners, and http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events for the available lifecycle events.